# CakePHP 2.x : too many queries with HABTM and belongsTo

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have these tables :

[image: Tables and foreign keys]

And in CakePHP, I have these models :

- **Author** hasMany **Post**
- **Post** belongsTo **Author**
- **Post** hasAndBelongsToMany **Tag**
- **Tag** hasAndBelongsToMany **Post**

What I would like this :

> For each tag, list all the related posts with its author.

So I will be able to do this, for example :

- tag1

  - post1 : by author1
  - post2 : by author2
- tag2

  - post3 : by author3
- tag3

  - post4 : by author4

All the models use the `Containable` behavior :

```
class AppModel extends Model
{
    public $recursive = -1;
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

The search :

```
$tags = $this->Tag->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Post' => array('Author')
    )
));
```

I get the good results :

[image: Good results]

But this search generates too many SQL queries :

[image: Too many queries]

I don't understand why CakePHP doesn't use SQL joins. I tried without Containable and recursive = 2 and there were as many queries as with Containable.

### My question

How to obtain the same result as the above image with a minimum of SQL queries? Currently, if there is a lot of data, there may be more than 100 SQL queries.

Sorry for the long post and language mistakes (I'm French), and thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AgRizzo I would like to have the same results as above (the var_dump) without having so many queries. Right now, if I have more than 20 authors and posts, there may be more than 100 SQL queries.